# How can I output the return value of a Method like totalAmount in an Spring Rest Entity

Tags: spring, rest, entity, hateoas

is it possible to output a return Value totalAmount of an Entity ShoppingCart that is not a Value in the Class but a Method? So for example I have a Class Shoppingcart with a List of Items. and a Method totalAmount. Now when I make a request to the API with the URL http://localhost:8082/carts/1 I want to get a response like the following:

```
{ 
"creationDate": "2016-12-07T09:45:38.000+0000",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo 2DS",
      "description": "Konsole from Nintendo",
      "price": 300.5,
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo Classic",
      "description": "Classic nintendo Console from the 80th...",
      "price": 75,
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ],
  "totalAmount": "1051,50",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "cart": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "checkout": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8083/order"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently the response of an API request looks like the following:

```
{
  "creationDate": "2016-12-07T09:45:38.000+0000",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo 2DS",
      "description": "Konsole from Nintendo",
      "price": 300.5,
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo Classic",
      "description": "Classic nintendo Console from the 80th...",
      "price": 75,
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "cart": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "checkout": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8083/order"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an Annotation that do this job or something other. I tried to add it in the CartResourceProcessor (org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceProcessor) but there is only the possibility to add additional links. Or do I need to add a Class value totalAmount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that by annotating your method with Jackson @JsonProperty annotation

Code sample

```
@JsonProperty("totalAmount")
public double computeTotalAmount()
{
    // compute totalAmout and return it
}
```

Comment: Yes @JsonProperty("totalAmount") do the job fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And to answer the possible next question you get after reading this. How the totalAmount is calculated. Here the snippet

```
public Class Cart{
   // some Class values

   @JsonProperty("totalAmount")
   public BigDecimal total(){

        return items.stream()
                .map(Item::total)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
}

public class Item{
     // some Item values

     @JsonProperty("totalAmount")
     public BigDecimal total(){
         return price.multiply(new BigDecimal(this.quantity));
     }
}
```

Outputs something similar to this:

```
{
  "creationDate": "2016-12-07T09:45:38.000+0000",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo 2DS",
      "description": "Konsole from Nintendo",
      "price": 300.5,
      "quantity": 3,
      "totalAmount": 901.5
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Nintendo Classic",
      "description": "Classic nintendo Console from the 80th...",
      "price": 75,
      "quantity": 2,
      "totalAmount": 150
    }
  ],
  "totalAmount": 1051.5,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "cart": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/carts/2"
    },
    "checkout": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8083/order"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you :)